# Starting and stopping Tomcat through ANT?

Tags: ant, tomcat6

I'm not sure this even makes sense, but I'm just following boss instructions.

Make an ANT script that compile the WAR, runs the tests, stops the server, deploys the WAR and then starts the server again.

How do I properly stop and start Tomcat through ANT?

Is it even a viable thing to do or should it be done in another way?

Note that the script should work without major changes on OS X, Linux and Windows.

Comment: Yes, it is viable; you can look how some IDEs do that (Netbeans generates ant build script which compiles/packs/deploys WAR and stops/starts tomcat for sure, almost sure Eclipse/Idea do that too). It's not too thankful task to write such a script by hand (mine is over 1k lines) though. As a starting point you may look here: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/ant/how-to-control-start-and-stop-of-a-tomcat-application-by-ant-build-s-2.html, however i'd rather delegate this task to IDE.

Comment: Everything is done Except Start and Stop. That's *all* I need to do now. (Thank god)

Comment: And yes, it is possible to make it in a rather portable way (just sotre specific settings in separate .porperties files): http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#implement-os-specific-configuration

Comment: The link goes to instructions involving the Tomcat Manager. I've propsed for this a lot but my boss wants it without the manager. Is this an option or just plain stupid?

Comment: @Meke: invoking system commands for starting/stopping tomcat does look strange to me, at least in dev environment...

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the Manager app (for example, http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=/footoo&war=file:/path/to/foo)

Also, is ANT running on same box as Tomcat?

Comment: @unhillbilly:There's no particular reason except that he states there might be issues with static content if it's not stopped before deployment.

Comment: @barti_ddu Well I imagine it's to be used in a live environment too

Comment: @Meke "Is this an option or just plain stupid?" I will say the latter. Modern APR-based Tomcats work just a like plain old Apache webserver for static files: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this a while back ago. It is possible. A part of what i did back then was copy a war into the webapps folder start the tomcat (asynchronously - used the antRunAsync script) and waited until the app was ready, if i rememebr right i used this (http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/integration/ant/task_runservertests.html) to ensure my app is ready. After everything was set up i executed my tests and after that i stopped tomcat again.

Comment: And you start and stop without root access..?

Answer (score 1):

Since you can not use manager, the only way I can think of is something like:

```
<exec dir="." executable="cmd" os="Windows NT">
    <arg line="/c 'tomcat.bat start'"/>
</exec>
<exec dir="." executable="sh" os="Linux">
    <arg line="-c 'tomcat.sh start'"/>
</exec>
```

..its quite clumsy, but at least it is an option.

Comment: To be fair - I'm not restricted to Not using the Manager, just I have to have a safe and working (and proper) solution